# aurelia error (0, _bootstrap2.default) is not a function

Tags: ecmascript-6, compilation, aurelia, ecmascript-5

I have an aurelia app for a filmfestival and recently I stumbled upon an error that I don't understand. 
I have a line of code:

`const timetableElement = $('<div>').attr('id', timetableID).addClass('timetable anim-fade-in');`

That after compiling it changes to

`var timetableElement = (0, _bootstrap2.default)('<div>').attr('id', timetableID).addClass('timetable anim-fade-in');`

Which result in the error:
`(0, _bootstrap2.default)` is not a function.

I hope I made myself a bit clear.

(www.suikerzoetfilmfestival.nl/programma)

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by adding
`declare var $`